# Save maximum decimal point in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to save a decimal number like 12.436783050324. But when i save it in a decimal(18,12) column it saves only 5 decimal points (12.436780000000). Can somebody please solve this issue. Thank you..

```
         DECLARE
        @CapitalizeAmount DECIMAL(18,12),
        @SheduleAmount      DECIMAL(36,12),
        @NewRebate          DECIMAL(18,12),
        @LostInterst DECIMAL(18,8)=0,
        @RebateRate                 DECIMAL(18,12)
        SELECT @SheduleAmount= SUM(A.IntBalance)  
        FROM destinity_LE_FacShedule AS A 
        WHERE A.facno =@FacNo
        AND A.Status IN ('N','S') 
        AND CAST(A.DueDate AS DATE) > CAST(@CurrentDate AS DATE) --0X00001
        AND A.RefCode IN ('RE','PP')

        SET @NewRebate =(@RebateRate *1.00000000000  *((@SheduleAmount- @LostInterst)/@SheduleAmount))
        SET @NewRebate=(case when @NewRebate<0 then 0 else @NewRebate END)
        SET @RebateRate =@NewRebate

        IF @RebateRate IS NULL 
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('REBATE RATE IS NULL!',16,1)
        END

        UPDATE destinity_LE_FACTermination
        SET OldRebate =@RebateRate
        FROM destinity_LE_FACTermination
        WHERE facno =@FacNo AND TerminationNo=@TerminationNo
```

Comment: How are you "saving it"?

Comment: UPDATE destinity_LE_FACTermination
    SET OldRebate =@RebateRate
    FROM destinity_LE_FACTermination
    WHERE facno =@FacNo AND TerminationNo=@TerminationNo

--OldRebate decimal(18,12)

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 1.000000000000? What is the data type of `A.IntBalance`?

Comment: I have added it into the question. Thank you.. :)

Comment: There is more going on in your code than you have posted here. @RebateRate is never set to anything so it would always be NULL in the code posted. The error would be raised every time.

Comment: its too big to post here, 
IntBalance is type of Money

Comment: You seem to have datatype issues all over the place here. You say that column is the money datatype but you declared a variable to hold the sum as decimal(36,12). That makes no sense. Money is only accurate to 4 decimal places. And 36??? Are we talking all the money on the planet * about 10 zillion? Aside from just getting the right value you really need to put in some time to sort our your dataytpes. Dealing with money requires attention to detail and what we have seen here does not demonstrate that.

Answer (score 2):

You have something strange going on:

```
declare @T table (dec decimal(18, 12));
declare @D decimal(18, 12) = 12.436783050324;
select @D;
insert into @T values (@D);
select * from @T;

---------------------------------------
12.436783050324

dec
---------------------------------------
12.436783050324
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code snippet and the calculation I believe the decimal trim is happening due to the difference in data type for @ScheduleAmount. Please can you try changing the data type in the snippet and test?

```
@SheduleAmount      DECIMAL(18,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution. Thanks for those who suggest answers. I really appreciate your advises. Here is my answer..

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateRebetRate]
(
@SheduleAmount float ,
@LostInterst float ,
@RebateRate float 
)
RETURNS float 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @NewRebate float
SET @NewRebate =(@RebateRate *1.00000000000  *((@SheduleAmount- @LostInterst)/@SheduleAmount))
SET @NewRebate=(case when @NewRebate<0 then 0 else @NewRebate END)
RETURN @NewRebate
END
```

Thank you..